# Can you calculate the charge after rubbing two objects

Tags: electrostatics, charge, insulators

If there are two insulators and you rub them together for a long time, is there a way to calculate how much charge should have transferred between them. I'm sure there is some relation to the triboelectric series and possibly surface area, but I am not sure if there is some formula for determining this. I am not too familiar with this material so I may be leaving out a key element. If that is the case please let me know.

Comment: The triboelectric series is semiquantitative, but I am not aware that there is a successful and reproducible theory of triboelectricity.